# Problems with water based paint sticking to 2 k primer

Tags: painting

I am having many problems with the aliphatic waterborne urethane paint( Performix 979s w/pigment)being applied over a 2K primer (Shopline JP331 brand). The paint becomes greasy feeling and peels right off. A light coat of paint is applied to the primer, then allowed to dry to touch, and is applied again until desired coverage. It is hung to dry for a three day cure time, not until then is it tested for peeling. And it does. The substrate is polyurethane. The paint was opened nearly a year ago, if not longer, and has been opened a few times to fill a gallon jug( from a five gallon bucket). Could this peeling come from leaching from the substrate or bad paint from age, or the primer and paint is not compatible?

Comment: Could you link the products in question please?  Google brings up gainer fuel, and a paint company that makes no 979.

Comment: so you're trying to use house paint over automotive primer? did you sand the primer lightly?